# Importing CSV in Python - why does a for loop over 'data' affect list(data) after it?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I'm importing a simple CSV file. I want to print its content line-by-line and then print it once again, but now as a list of lists representing each line. The following code:

```
fo = open('filename.csv', 'r')
content = csv.reader(fo)

for each in content:
    print(each)

print("Content as a list: ", list(content))
fo.close()
```

works as expected for the first task, but then prints an empty list after 'Content as a list'. If I comment the for loop out, I get the desired result, though. Why does the for loop affect the `list(content)` below?

Comment: you consumed the iterator, so there's nothing left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csv.reader function returns an iterator, which can be iterated over only once. [How to use csv reader object multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42903157/how-to-use-csv-reader-object-multiple-times)

[Why can't I iterate twice over the same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data)

One of the solutions would be to convert it to a list:

```
fo = open('filename.csv', 'r')
content = list(csv.reader(fo))
fo.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, as a beginner in Python, I wasn't aware of the difference between an iterator and an iterable object. The links you provided are very useful.